# Auto-convert link click to pushState call

Tags: javascript, html, onbeforeunload, pushstate

Is it possible to define some sort of event handler for when a user clicks on any link on the page, and in this handler to decide if the current page can update itself to become the page at the location or if  a complete refresh needs to be done?

For example when I have the following 2 pages:

**home page**

```
<h1>Home</h1>
<a href="http://example.com/">Home</a>
<a href="http://example.com/subsite">Subsite</a>
<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
```

**sub page**

```
<h1>Subsite</h1>
<a href="http://example.com/">Home</a>
<a href="http://example.com/subsite">Subsite</a>
<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
```

Both those pages can be rendered by the same javascript client, which is also loaded with the page. So, if one is on the Home page, he already loaded the client that is able to render the site Subsite, so if one clicks on the Link "Subsite", the client should be able to kick in and tell the browser "Hey, you don't have to do a new request to the server, I can handle this for you!"

I imagine something like this:

```
window.addEventListener("visitpage", function(e){
    if(client.canRender(e.url)){  //decide if we will update the page by ourself, or if the browser needs to do a request to the server
        client.render(e.url);
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

I already know that there is the `history.pushState()` function to tell the browser that we're now on another url, but it is not doing what I want. It's just related to the topic. What I am searching for is a way to prevent the browser from leaving the page if I'm able to display the page that the browser would get from the server by javascript. Automatically.

I really don't want to add an event event listener to every single link on the page that calls `preventDefault` and then `pushState` to change the url to what the link would have changed it. I'm searching for a solution that would even work, if I'd do something like this in javascript:

```
window.location = "/subsite"
```

Is that possible?